# Unable to Predict the custom trained mobilenet in browser using TensorflowJS

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I am new to TensorflowJS and Javascript. I trained a mobilenet with images of diamonds using Tensorflow Object Detection so that it can detect Diamonds. The model is saved in SavedModel format. I converted the SavedModel format into TFJSgraphmodel format using the tensorflowjs_convertor.py and it created a model.json and 29 Shard file.
I am using this [https://github.com/dkreider/tensorflowjs-cat-vs-dog] tutorial which is very similar in functionality of uploading a image and predicting after a button is pressed.
I changed the `await tf.loadLayersModel` to `await tf.loadGraphModel` in its index.js file, as converting from SAvedModel to LayerModel is not supported, I have to use loadGraphModel.

I tried the below code to predict on Click

```
async function initialize() {
    try{
        model = await tf.loadGraphModel('trained-model/model.json');
    }catch(e) {
       console.log("The model is not loaded") 
    }
    
    classifierElement.style.display = 'block';
    loaderElement.style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById('predict').addEventListener('click', () => predict());    
}

async function predict () {

  const imageElement = document.getElementById('img');
  let tensorImg = tf.browser.fromPixels(imageElement).cast('int32').resizeNearestNeighbor([640, 640]);
  const t4d=tensorImg.expandDims(0);
  t4d.print() 
  console.log(typeof(t4d))

  data = await t4d.data()

  const prediction = model.executeAsync(t4d).then(prediction=> { 
    const data = prediction.dataSync() // you can also use arraySync or their equivalents async methods
    console.log('Predictions: ', data);
  })
```

But when I run it, I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'backend' of undefined
    at e.t.moveData (tfjs:17)
    at e.t.get (tfjs:17)
    at Object.dG [as kernelFunc] (tf.min.js:17)
    at n (tfjs:17)
    at tfjs:17
    at e.t.scopedRun (tfjs:17)
    at e.t.runKernelFunc (tfjs:17)
    at e.t.runKernel (tfjs:17)
    at reshape_ (tf.min.js:17)
    at reshape__op (tf.min.js:17)
```

Kindly help, I am stuck on this for many days.
Thanks

Comment: I was seeing something similar in a Vue3 webapp. If I made the class containing the model unreactive then the error magically went away. e.g.: this.$model = new MyTensorFlow()